# Optimize MySQL Query using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a query with execution plan as below and is taking more than 20 seconds to execute how can i optimize it

```
EXPLAIN  SELECT c.coupon_id as c_id, `c` . *, `st`.`name` AS `store` FROM `coupon` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `store` AS `st` ON st.store_id = c.store_id GROUP BY `c`.`coupon_id` ORDER BY `c`.`created` desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | index  | NULL          | idx_created | 5       | NULL                  |  200 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | st    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | sonicdevel.c.store_id |    1 |                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**INDEXES**

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM coupon;
+--------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| coupon |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | coupon_id     | A         |      219557 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | store_id          |            1 | store_id      | A         |       16889 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | coupon_fid        |            1 | coupon_fid    | A         |      219557 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | name              |            1 | name          | A         |      219557 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_expiry_date   |            1 | expiry_date   | A         |       12915 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_created       |            1 | created       | A         |      219557 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_seo_url       |            1 | seo_url       | A         |      219557 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_start_date    |            1 | start_date    | A         |       43911 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_todays_coupon |            1 | todays_coupon | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_counter       |            1 | counter       | A         |          63 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | front_page        |            1 | front_page    | A         |         218 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| coupon |          1 | idx_approved      |            1 | approved      | A         |         218 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+


SHOW INDEX FROM store;
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| store |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | store_id    | A         |        5237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| store |          0 | fid         |            1 | store_fid   | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| store |          1 | top_store   |            1 | top_store   | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| store |          1 | name        |            1 | name        | A         |        5237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| store |          1 | idx_seo_url |            1 | seo_url     | A         |        5237 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| store |          1 | idx_status  |            1 | status      | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| store |          1 | name_2      |            1 | name        | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| store |          1 | name_2      |            2 | tags        | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| store |          1 | name_2      |            3 | short_desc  | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| store |          1 | name_2      |            4 | long_desc   | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into optimizing the query itself, I'm going to suggest looking at temporary table use in your query plan. You will notice they are showing up in the explain detail under the extra column.

temp table settings in my.cnf

[max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) = ?

This variable sets the maximum size to which user-created MEMORY tables are permitted to grow. The value of the variable is used to calculate MEMORY table MAX_ROWS values.

[tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) = ?

The maximum size of internal in-memory temporary tables. (The actual limit is determined as the minimum of tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size.) **If an in-memory temporary table exceeds the limit, MySQL automatically converts it to an on-disk MyISAM table.**

From the [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215163/optimal-mysql-temporary-tables-memory-tables-configuration)

> Tmp_table_size is the largest a table can be in memory when it is
>   created automatically by a query. But this can't be larger than
>   max_heap_table_size anyway. So there's no benefit to setting
>   tmp_table_size greater than max_heap_table_size. It's common to set
>   these two config variables to the same value.

How many temp tables were created and on disk ?

```
mysql> show global status like 'Created%'; 
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 20    |
| Created_tmp_files       | 6     |
| Created_tmp_tables      | 43    |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

Keeping that in mind, it would be helpful to know how IOs are affecting query performance. You can monitor that activity with tools like [IOTOP](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) and [vmstat](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vmstat8.html) / [vmstat how to](https://library.linode.com/linux-tools/common-commands/vmstat). My point being that optimizing the query syntax is just one option among many to make your querys run faster.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, that you are selecting everything from `coupon`. Why should MySQL have a look in the index when it has to read the whole data anyway? If you don't have to select everything from a table, never use `SELECT *`. Another thing is, that this data also has to be transported.

And do you know, that you don't get reliable data? When you use `GROUP BY` you have to adjust your `SELECT` clause. Every column you select should either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function should be applied to it. If you don't follow that rule, MySQL selects a random row from that group.

Fix above issues, and I'm sure 90% of your problems with that query are gone. The 10% left you can solve with compound indexes. For example an index on (coupon_id, created).

Comment: *"Every column you select should either be in the GROUP BY clause or an aggregate function"* - This isn't true, although MySQL's implementation of group by is very loose, since `Coupon_ID` is the primary key, there is no reason why other columns in the table can't be selected since they are functionally dependant on `Coupon_ID`, this is allowed by the SQL Standard. i.e. There will only ever be one value of `c.Created` per `c.Coupon_ID` so the grouping on `created` is implied by the grouping `Coupon_ID`, so the *random* row selected won't be random at all, there is only 1 to choose from

Comment: Although I do agree that using `SELECT *` is never a good idea.

Comment: I haven't said, that it can't be done, I just said, that a random row of that group will be returned. And you're wrong when stating that "there will only ever be one value of c.Created per c.Coupon_ID".

Comment: `Coupon_ID` is the primary key of the `coupon` table, it is, by definition, unique (only 1 row per value) so hence there can only value of `created` per `coupon_id`. If you still believe I am wrong I have [created an sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/121107/1), I would love to see you produce two different values for created for a single `coupon_ID`.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, guess I haven't had enough coffee yet today.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the bottleneck in the query was **ORDER BY `c`.`created` DESC**.

The table coupon have `auto_increment` **PK** `coupon_id` and the field `created` is also of type INT where `unix timestamp` is stored, So I observed that can do `ORDER BY coupon_id DESC` instead of `created` which i found executes query in 0.00 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
given that both coupon_id and store_id is a PK, i don't see the reason for the GROUP BY
The FROM part select 1 row per coupon_id, the join statement joins exactly 1 (1:1 relationship) row to it, so the GROUP BY is not needed at all, so that may be one way to slightly imporve the speed